# Passing Struct members in Functions

Tags: c, function, struct

I want to pass struct members in function . I don't mean something like that:

```
struct smth
{
  int n;
};

void funct(struct smth s);
```

I want these structs

```
struct student {
char name[50];
int semester;
};

struct prof {
char name[50];
char course[50];
};

struct student_or_prof {
  int flag;
  int size;
  int head;
   union {
     struct student student;
     struct prof prof;
   }
}exp1;
struct student_or_prof *stack;
struct student_or_prof exp2;
```

To pass their members in a fucntion with variables not struct variables

```
int pop(int head,int n)
{
 if(head==n)
  return 1;
 else head++;
}
```

Because i don't want to use the function for structs only. Is it possible?

**EDIT** I want the numbers also to change , not return , something like pointer.

**EDIT_2** Also i know that this pop(exp1.head,n) it works, but i want also the exp1.head to change after the end of the function pop.

Comment: you can pass the address of struct variable and use it. you need some other way than pointers?

Comment: I want every possible way , but i want also the number of the member of the struct that i sent to function also to change  that's why i mentioned pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pointers. pass poniter to exp1.head and manipulate it by dereferencing it in function as,

```
int pop(int * head,int n)
{
 if(*head==n)
  return 1;
 else (*head)++;
}
```

call function as,

```
pop(&exp1.head,n);
```

Comment: Yes ! Exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 3):

First things first, you are missing a semicolon, after the `union` definition inside the `struct student_or_prof`.

As per your edit #2, you should be passing the address of the variable, taking it as a pointer to a variable by the function, and then editing/incrementing the content of the address (the variable that pointer points to). Like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student_or_prof {
    int head;
} exp1;

int pop( int * head, int n ) {
    if ( *head == n )
        return 1;
    else (*head)++;
}

int main( ){

    int returnval;

    exp1.head = 5;
    returnval = pop( &exp1.head, 10 );
    printf( "%d", exp1.head );

    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

This will print a `6`. Here, I am passing the address of the `exp1.head`, so that the function `pop` can refer to the actual `exp1.head` you have in your hands. Otherwise, the `pop` will be only informed about the value that `exp1.head` had, copy that value into its own `head` variable, play around with that.

And also, it would be sensible to return some `int` from the `pop` in any case. Right now it returns a value only when `*head == n` is satisfied, and returns something that wouldn't make sense. I don't think you'd want that, so:

```
...
else {
    (*head)++;
    return 0;
}
...
```

Would be better.

If you don't like the parenthesis around the `*head`, then you may want to use `... += 1;` instead of a postfix increment, which has less precedence over the dereferencing operator `*`.